# Estimation of pipe bending radius based on shape of clearance inside

Tags: geometry

Suppose that we have a pipe which is bent a little, so if we put a light source in one end of it, I think that at the other end we see a shape of a crescent moon, i.e.,

[image]

I suppose that such a shape could be parametrized by a tuple ***p*** of 3 parameters: radius of the left-side circular arc, radius of the right side circular arc and the distance between origins of circles underlying these arcs.

Assuming some shape of the pipe bending, like toroidal, is it possible to estimate the bending parameters, like bend radius, from the parameters of clearance ***p***? Is it some simple geometry or could you show some references?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "we see a shape of a biconvex lens".

Comment: try solving a 2d anulus first

Comment: I have understood : you mean the **cross-section** of a biconvex lens, otherwise said the intersection of two disks. Why do you think to 2 parameters ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Excuse me, probably except the confusion I also made wrong assumptions about the shape of the clearance. I edited the question, hope that now it is written more clearly.

Comment: @JeanMarie But yes, I meant the cross-section of a biconvex lens, but now I suppose the clearance will be rather in the shape of a crescent moon.